# If a programming language is 64bit, does that mean it is better than 32bit?

Tags: programming-languages, 64-bit

If a language says it has 32bit or 64bit (php or other), does that mean that 64bit is somehow "better"?  Is it faster?  More reliable?

Comment: Short answer: not necessarily "better" or faster. Does not imply more reliable. @H2CO3, it's twice as bittier!

Comment: To me, that would mean the language is capable of using 64-bit addressing, therefore able to store more things (objects) in memory and also perhaps provide for faster implementations.

Comment: @Houdini Such as copying data in 8-byte chunks - twice as fast.

Comment: @H2CO3 Copying memory is limited by memory bandwidth and should not be expected to be twice faster just because 64-bit instructions are used.

Comment: The code generator in a compiler doesn't have anything to do with the language.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Not even roughly?

Comment: Languages aren't 32 bit or 64 bit. Language implementations are.

Comment: @H2CO3 I would benchmark it but I would have to find how to flush the cache on my system, and life is just too short. But roughly, I would expect the performance of copying **uncached** memory with 32- or 64-bit instruction to be closer to identical than to a factor of 2 (all the time being spent waiting on cache lines that are the same size regardless of the instruction set currently being executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“A 64-bit compiler” usually means that it is generating instructions from the x86-64 instruction set instead of the IA-32 instruction set. The former is more modern and benefits from more experience in the design of efficient instruction sets. On the other hand, the same L1 cache (resp. L2 cache, L3 cache, cacheline) fits only half as many 64-bit words as it fits 32-bit words. In practice, performance is about the same, and memory use is higher with 64-bit instructions, but 64-bit programs are not limited to 4GiB of virtual memory space like 32-bit programs are.

Comment: Thanks.  When would I need to go beyond using 4GB of memory?  What kind of applications needs that?

Comment: @johnny One demo by Apple when they made the switch to 64-bit and needed to explain it to their customers was editing in Photoshop (or a similar program) a very large bitmap image: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id5vpy2CapY